# Setting navigation controller's delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'm following a guide to create custom transitions and he does is create a NSObject that looks like :

```
class CustomNavigationAnimationController: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerForOperation operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, fromViewController fromVC: UIViewController, toViewController toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {

    if fromVC.isKindOfClass(VC2) {
        return showTrans()
    } else if fromVC.isKindOfClass(VC3){
        return dismissTrans()
    } else {
        return nil
    }

}

}
```

then in another file he makes two classes with functions showTrans / dismissTrans and the classes look like:

```
  class showTrans: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {  
    func animateTransition(transitionContext:    UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView()
    let fromVC = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)!
    let toVC = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)!

    containerView?.addSubview(fromVC.view)
    containerView?.addSubview(toVC.view)

    toVC.view.alpha = 0

    UIView.animateWithDuration(transitionDuration(transitionContext), delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: [], animations: { 
        toVC.view.alpha = 1
    }) { (finished: Bool) in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
    }

}
func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
    return 0.7
}
```

At the very beginning of the video he goes into the storyboard and clicks on his navigation controller and there are 4 buttons up at the top for Navigation Controller/ First Responder/ Exit / Delegate. He clicks on the delegate button and sets the Nav Bar's delegate to the CustomNavigationAnimationController class. When I click on the Navigation controller I only get the Nav Controller/ First Responder/ Exit buttons up at the top.

How do I connect the classes/transition code to the navigation controller?

Comment: Can you see a arrow mark in the navigation controller in story board. click that arrow mark, you will see navigation bar, then right click on that to get the delegate. Let me know if it works..

Comment: Somehow I completely missed that he had dragged in an NSObject to the top bit and then dragged the delegate like you said. Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the storyboard click on Navigation Controller.Add an NSObject from object library to your nav bar.  On top of the view four buttons you can see (as you said in the question - Nav Controller/ First Responder/ NSObject /Exit buttons). Right Click on the first button. you will get navigation controller action lists. From there under **Outlets** select delegate and drag to NSObject. Connect the NSObject to your Class.

Answer (score 1):

You can see an arrow mark in the navigation controller in story board. click that arrow mark, you will see navigation bar, then right click on that to get the delegate.

Here is the snapshot to make it easy for you

[image]